# JDBC trying to retrieve salt from MySQL database with null parameter

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a JDBC method to retrieve salt from a user, in order to validate the user, when logging in.

Here is my method:

```
 public static byte[] getSaltMethod(String username) throws SQLException, LoginSampleException {

    try {

        Connection con = Connector.connection();

        String SQL = "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE email = '?'";

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        statement.setString(1, username);


        ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();

        while (set.next()) {

            byte[] salt = set.getBytes("salt");

            /* jeg er i tivil om denne skal være her*/

            return salt;
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Conf.MYLOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new LoginSampleException(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;

}
}
```

I have used the debugger to try and identify the problem and I get this error message

```
"Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)."
```

I have tried both with and without the ' around the parameter, but it gives me a syntax error instead.

Comment: Don't put the `?` between single quotes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Whenever i do this, i get a syntax-error instead

Comment: if i place this string in MySQL workbench it returns the salt, like it should, but without the single quote i get a syntax error

Comment: what's the syntax error you get?

Comment: Unknown column 'salt' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL shouldn't contains `'` (binding) characters around the parameters.

Characters will be added automatically by the [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Change SQL to:

```
  String SQL = "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE email = ?";
```